# K Means Image segmentation fail

Tags: python, algorithm, python-2.7, k-means, image-segmentation

I'm currently making an image segmentation program using the K-means Algorithm.

Here is the summary of what i'm doing :

- Creating N Centroids with a lite spread algorithm (got better result
  than random)
- Assign each pixel to the closest centroid
- Change centroid position to the "center of mass"
- Repeat 2 and 3 until nothing change anymore

To determinate the center of mass, i'm taking the average position of all pixels assigned to the centroid.

My Problem is when the picture is really simple it's work fine :

[Working picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6iDRz.jpg)

But when i use a more complexe picture (and this picture is not "really complexe" at all)

[Fail picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5moK0.jpg)

I'm not really sure of why this is not working fine, i double checked my code,and can't see anything wrong on the algorithm, and the problem is not from the algorithm choice i think because a lot of people over the internet show picture with good segmentation with the K means

If you have some idea of how i could improve my result ...

Here is my code if you want to test it on you own.

I'm using python 2.7

My Algo.py :

```
from PIL import Image
from Pixel import Pixel
from Centroid import Centroid
import Tools
import random

class Algo:

    def run(self, inputPath, outputPath, nbCluster, nbIteration):
        size, pixelList = self.getImageData(inputPath)

        centroidArray = self.initCentroid(size, pixelList, nbCluster)

        for iteration in range(0, nbIteration):
            print "Iteration : " + str(iteration)
            self.clearCentroidsMembers(centroidArray)
            self.assignCentroidToPixel(pixelList, centroidArray)
            self.moveCentroid(centroidArray)

        self.printResult(outputPath, size, centroidArray)


    def clearCentroidsMembers(self, centroidArray):
        for centroid in centroidArray:
            centroid.members = []

    def assignCentroidToPixel(self, pixelList, centroidArray):
        for pixel in pixelList:
            minDist = 100000;
            closestCentroid = None
            for centroid in centroidArray:
                dist = Tools.getDistance(pixel.graphCoordinate, centroid.graphCoordinate)
                if dist < minDist:
                    minDist = dist
                    closestCentroid = centroid
            closestCentroid.members.append(pixel)

    def moveCentroid(self, centroidArray):
        for centroid in centroidArray:
            newPos = Tools.getCenterOfMass(centroid.members)
            if newPos == None:
                newPos = centroid.graphCoordinate
            centroid.graphCoordinate = newPos


    def initCentroid(self, size, pixelList, nbCluster):
        centroidArray = []

        randomPixelPos = random.randint(0, len(pixelList) - 1)
        graphCoordinate = pixelList[randomPixelPos].graphCoordinate
        centroid = Centroid(graphCoordinate)
        centroidArray.append(centroid)

        for i in range(1, nbCluster):
            maxDist = 0
            graphCoordinate = None
            for pixel in pixelList:
                dist = 0
                for centroid in centroidArray:
                    dist += Tools.getDistance(pixel.graphCoordinate, centroid.graphCoordinate)
                dist = dist / len(centroidArray)
                if dist > maxDist:
                    maxDist = dist
                    graphCoordinate = pixel.graphCoordinate
            centroid = Centroid(graphCoordinate)
            centroidArray.append(centroid)


        return centroidArray

    def printResult(self, path, size, centroidArray):
        for centroid in centroidArray:
            pixelList = []
            for i in range(0, size[0] * size[1]):
                pixelList.append((0, 0, 0))
            for pixel in centroid.members:
                pixelList[pixel.picturePosition] = pixel.graphCoordinate
            resultImage = Image.new("RGB", size)
            resultImage.putdata(pixelList)
            resultImage.save(path + "out-" +    str(centroidArray.index(centroid)) + ".jpg")


    def getImageData(self, inputPath):
        image = Image.open(inputPath)
        image = image.convert("RGB")
        size = image.size
        pixelList = []
        for y in range(0, size[1]):
            for x in range(0, size[0]):
                color = image.getpixel((x, y))
                pixelPos = y * size[0] + x
                pixel = Pixel(pixelPos, color)
                pixelList.append(pixel)
        return size, pixelList
```

My Tools.py :

```
import math

def getDistance(pos1, pos2):
    dist = math.sqrt( math.pow(pos2[0] - pos1[0], 2) + math.pow(pos2[1] - pos1[1], 2) + math.pow(pos2[2] - pos2[2], 2) )
    return dist

def getCenterOfMass(pixelArray):
    if len(pixelArray) == 0:
        return None

    center = [0, 0, 0]

    for pixel in pixelArray:
        center[0] += pixel.graphCoordinate[0]
        center[1] += pixel.graphCoordinate[1]
        center[2] += pixel.graphCoordinate[2]

    center[0] /= len(pixelArray)
    center[1] /= len(pixelArray)
    center[2] /= len(pixelArray)

    return (center[0], center[1], center[2])
```

Here is Pixel.py :

```
class Pixel:

    def __init__(self, position, coordinate):
        self.graphCoordinate = coordinate
        self.picturePosition = position
```

Here is Centroid.py :

```
class Centroid:

    def __init__(self, coordinate):
        self.graphCoordinate = coordinate
        self.members = []
```

And finally main.py

```
from Algo import Algo

algo = Algo();
algo.run("input/Stonehenge.jpg", "output/", 3, 100)
```

Comment: `Algo.py` has an indentation issue.  Can you double check the file?

Comment: edited, sorry for that

Comment: What result are you expecting?  It looks to me as if your code is doing a pretty good job of separating dark, light, and medium values from the photo.

Comment: i would like, 3 part, the grass the sky and the stone. I don't really know if Kmeans can do that, but would like to segment my image, and here the segmentation look broken. should i go to another algo ?

Comment: I'm looking for something like this : http://postimg.org/image/f0jayzwpb/  thought that kMeans could to that

Comment: Try segmenting based on hue and saturation (ignoring brightness) instead of RGB values. You'll have to make the distance function "wrap around" for hue.

Comment: Hi, i tried to work with Hue and saturation, but i'm have some problem, it's due (i think) to how i get the distance between two point. You said that i have to change my distance function, but i'm not sure of what do you mean with : a distance function "wrap around" for hue. Have you some exemples or link. I checked online but i didn't really understand

Comment: Hum, i changed a litle my code, i was converting my color in a bad way. I'm now very close to my goal : http://postimg.org/image/u97hhww8t/ , but, i'm still using and euclidian distance. I red more informations about the HSV color space, and i think that a better distance calculation can exist